window remains behind on click
Quite simple situation: each time I click on a HTTP(s) link in any program, Firefox (already launched) doesn't show up over the current window, instead a "is ready" notification appears, which I have to click to get the browser to show. Is this a known bug and has a solution been found?
Ubuntu 24.04 LTS
